# How to select right template for class

Tags: c++

As an input, I'm given a number, which is a bit-width of a variable. For ex. if it's 5, I need to use char(which is 8), if I'm given 14, i need to use 16-bit int.
I'm free to use STD lib and all of standards up to C++17.

I've created class, but I can't find how can I create instance without enclosing brackets. I don't know how can I create such object without specifying class template, not even as a pointer.

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Kompresor{
...
};

int main(int agrc, char* argv[]){

    size_t max_value = argv[1];
    size_t copy = max_value + 1;
    int byte_width = 0;
    while(copy > 0){
        copy = copy >> 1;
        ++byte_width;
    }
    // This works
    // Problem is brackets, can't use kompresor outside scope
    if(byte_width < 9){
        Kompresor<char> Kompresor();
    }else if(byte_width < 17){
        Kompresor<int16_t> Kompresor();
    }
    // This dosen't
    Kompresor<>* k;
    k = new Kompresor<char>();

    return 0;
}
```

I need to use object throughout program, and writing same code in all of enclosing brackets is just code redundancy.

Comment: Couldn't you use [std::bitset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)?

Comment: ´std::bitset´ if your size is given at compiletime
´boost::dynamic_bitset´ if you need a runtime size bitset

Comment: Templates are in general resolved at compile time. You could create objects of all possible types upfront and only use one, but the question is *why*. Why do you have such a constraint? Can't you use the biggest possible type always?

Comment: or just use a 'std::vector<uint8_t>' to build a simple dynamic bitset, no templates needed

Comment: @Yksisarvinen It's not space efficient.

Comment: To rest, I apologize, I didin't mention it. The size is not known at compile time, it's passed as arg on command line.

Comment: use a template function that perfor the rest of computation depending on the correct type, or create a base class so that you can have a common pointer for storing any of those classes

Comment: @skeller I can't use boost.

Comment: "The size is not known at compile time, it's passed as arg on command line" - with a `main` signature of `int main()`, noone could have guessed that. Please make your question code more like your *actual* code - [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know size at compile time, I resorted to using 
`std::vector<uint8_t>`, and keeping track of vector size, thanks @skeller, and rest of you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a template function to do the full job, and dispatch in main:

```
template <typename T>
void DoJob()
{
    Kompresor<T> k;
    // ...
}
```

and in main

```
int main()
{
    std::size_t size = /*...*/

    switch (size)
    {
        case 8: DoJob<char>(); break;
        case 16: DoJob<std::uint16_t>(); break;
        case 32: DoJob<std::uint32_t>(); break;
        case 64: DoJob<std::uint64_t>(); break;
        default: throw std::runtime_error("unsupported");
    }

}
```